# Upload media file on twitter from android

Tags: android, twitter, media, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

Here is my code that upload media file on twitter from android after a bit searching i just finally make it running i am posting here so that any one want to do the same work so that he/she can save time :)

here is my mainlayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Twitter Login Button -->
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnLoginTwitter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login with Twitter"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip"/>

    <!-- user name label -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/lblUserName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip"/>

    <!-- label update status -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/lblUpdate"
        android:text="Update Status"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <!-- Tweet EditText -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/txtUpdateStatus"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <!-- Tweet Button -->
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnUpdateStatus"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tweet"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


     <Button android:id="@+id/btnUploadVideo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Upload Video"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <!-- Twitter Logout button -->
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogoutTwitter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Logout from Twitter"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
        android:visibility="gone"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

In order to implement twitter oAuth in your application you need twitter consumer key and consumer secret which are used to make twitter API calls. So register a new twitter application and get the keys

1. Go to https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new and register new application. Fill application name, description and website.
2. Give some dummy url in the callback url field to make the app as browser app. (If you leave it as blank it will act as Desktop app which won’t work in mobile device)
3. Under the settings tab upload icon and change the access type to Read and Write.
4. Create a new project in Eclipse File New ⇒ Android ⇒ Application Project and fill the required details.
   After creating project open AndroidManifest.xml file and paste the following code. I added following code to manifest file

   - INTERNET Permission
   - ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE Permission
   - and added an Intent Filter

Here is the code :-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "Your Key";
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "Your KEY";

 // Preference Constants
    static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
    static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";

    static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample";

    // Twitter oauth urls
    static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";

    // Login button
    Button btnLoginTwitter;
    // Update status button
    Button btnUpdateStatus;
    // Logout button
    Button btnLogoutTwitter;
    // EditText for update

    EditText txtUpdate;
    // lbl update
    TextView lblUpdate;
    TextView lblUserName;

    // Progress dialog
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Twitter twitte;
    // Twitter
    private static Twitter twitter;
    private static RequestToken requestToken;
     File file;
    // Shared Preferences
    private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    // Internet Connection detector
    private ConnectionDetector cd;

    // Alert Dialog Manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();



    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
           StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

         if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                // Internet Connection is not present
                alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                        "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
                // stop executing code by return
                return;
            }

         if(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY.trim().length() == 0 || TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET.trim().length() == 0){
                // Internet Connection is not present
                alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Twitter oAuth tokens", "Please set your twitter oauth tokens first!", false);
                // stop executing code by return
                return;
            }

         btnLoginTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginTwitter);
            btnUpdateStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateStatus);
            btnLogoutTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogoutTwitter);
            txtUpdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUpdateStatus);
            lblUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUpdate);
            lblUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUserName);

            // Shared Preferences
            mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                    "MyPref", 0);


            btnLoginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // Call login twitter function
                    loginToTwitter();
                }
            });


            if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
                Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
                if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
                    // oAuth verifier
                    String verifier = uri
                            .getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

                    try {
                        // Get the access token
                        AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                                requestToken, verifier);

                        // Shared Preferences
                        Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();

                        // After getting access token, access token secret
                        // store them in application preferences
                        e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                        e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                                accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                        // Store login status - true
                        e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                        e.commit(); // save changes

                        Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());

                        // Hide login button
                        btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        // Show Update Twitter
                        lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        // Getting user details from twitter
                        // For now i am getting his name only
                        long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                        User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                        String username = user.getName();

                        // Displaying in xml ui
                        lblUserName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Welcome " + username + "</b>"));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // Check log for login errors
                        Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }




            btnUpdateStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Call update status function
                    // Get the status from EditText
                    String status = txtUpdate.getText().toString();

                    // Check for blank text
                    if (status.trim().length() > 0) {
                        // update status
                        new updateTwitterStatus().execute(status);
                    } else {
                        // EditText is empty
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Please enter status message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();

                    }
                }
            });


            btnLogoutTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // Call logout twitter function
                    logoutFromTwitter();
                }
            });




    }



    private void logoutFromTwitter() {
        // Clear the shared preferences
        Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN);
        e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET);
        e.remove(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN);
        e.commit();

        // After this take the appropriate action
        // I am showing the hiding/showing buttons again
        // You might not needed this code
        btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lblUserName.setText("");
        lblUserName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void loginToTwitter() {
        // Check if already logged in
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            Configuration configuration = builder.build();

            TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
            twitter = factory.getInstance();

            try {
                requestToken = twitter
                        .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            // user already logged into twitter
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Show Update Twitter
            lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnuploadvideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check user already logged in your application using twitter Login flag is
     * fetched from Shared Preferences
     * */
    private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
        // return twitter login status from Shared Preferences
        return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
    }




    /**
     * Function to update status
     * */
    class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting Places JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);
            String status = args[0];
            file=new File("/mnt/sdcard/1.mp4");
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

                // Access Token 
                String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                // Access Token Secret
                String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

                AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);


                try {
                    uploadPic(file, status, twitter);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
               // Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog and show
         * the data in UI Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI
         * from background thread, otherwise you will get error
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    // Clearing EditText field
                    txtUpdate.setText("");
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public void uploadPic(File file, String message, Twitter twitter)
            throws Exception {
        try {
            StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(message);
            status.setMedia(file);
            Status state = twitter.updateStatus(status);

            Log.d("Responce", state.getText());

        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("TAG", "Pic Upload error" + e.getErrorMessage());
            // throw e;
        }

        Log.d("Responce","failed");
    }
```

ConnectionDetector.Java

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

    private Context _context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
        this._context = context;
    }


    public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null)
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null)
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }


}
```

AlertDialogManager.java

```
public class AlertDialogManager {

    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message,
            Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        if(status != null)
            // Setting alert dialog icon
            alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Hafiz, i have done the same thing for posting single image. Can you please let me know how to post multiple photos in a single tweet. I have also posted the question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113844/posting-multiple-photos-in-a-single-tweet.
Thanks